# Заполнение таблицы из массива (Flask)

Tags: python, flask

задача следующая, мне необходимо получить номера заказов и даты их создания по API из МойСклад, что собственно я делаю следующим образом:
Файл ms.py с функциями по парсу:

```html
def getordersz():
    path = "entity/purchaseorder"
    limit = 8
    resp = requests.get(f"{URL_API}{path}?limit={limit}", headers=headers).json()
    for orderznum in resp['rows']:
        print ([orderznum['name'], orderznum['moment']])
    value = orderznum
    return value
GETORDERSZ = getordersz()
```

Данный участок кода работает корректно, и выводит список , подобный этому:

```html
['00232', '2019-07-27 20:35:00']
['00100', '2020-11-18 20:53:00']
['00267', '2019-08-27 19:01:00']
['00059', '2020-10-08 16:41:00']
['00111', '2020-12-30 12:39:00']
['00206', '2019-07-10 20:27:00']
['00329', '2019-10-17 17:54:00']
['00044', '2019-03-21 09:52:00']
```

В конце я присвоил переменной GETORDERSZ значение из функции, которое она вернула.
После в файле app.py
В нем делаю импорт из файла ms этой переменной `from ms import GETORDERSZ`
И прописываю путь:

```html
@app.route('/postavka')
def postavka():
    return render_template("postavka.html", dataz=GETORDERSZ)
```

В самом шаблоне postavka.html я прописываю:

```
 {% for table in dataz %}
<div class="col">
{{ dataz }}
</div>
  {% endfor %}
```

По итогу я получаю вот такой вывод страницы : https://yadi.sk/i/4Deof5lSpl5rDw

Я не понимаю , каким образом здесь оказываются данные в JSON ,если до этого функция уже вернула все в формате списка. Что нужно сделать, чтобы корректно вывести таблицу с данными? Чтобы в первом столбце разместить данные по нулевому индексу списка, во втором по первому и т.д?

Comment: Вы в функции делаете возврат `return value`, а чуть ранее делаете присваивание `value = orderznum`, при этом обращения вида `orderznum['name']` намекают, что `orderznum` это всё-таки словарь. Значит получается, что `value` это тоже словарь, функция возвращает словарь и этот словарь выводится в шаблоне (и это кстати вообще не JSON)

Comment: Как раз мне и нужно, чтобы функция выводила массив , а дальше распарсить этот массив по ячейкам в столбцах. Что нужно для этого?